# "variable".Bounds.IntersectsWith

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, collision-detection, bounds

How do I make the do while loop in my code work with z being a variable?

```
Function make(ByVal z As Object)
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.location = zloc
    Do While z.bounds.intersectswith(PictureBox1.Bounds, PictureBox2.Bounds, PictureBox3.Bounds)
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
        z.location = zloc
    Loop
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()
    Return (z)
End Function
```

The problem is I cant use the ".bounds.intersectswith" on a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem really comes from the fact that `z` is declared as `Object`. `Object` by itself does not have any properties (well, only the really basic ones). It certainly does not have a `bounds` property or method, so you can't use that.

What you need to do is declare `z` as its actual type (whatever that is in your code) and you will be able to access its properties. Otherwise, if you really need to use `Object` as argument in your method, you should cast `z` to the correct type in the method, using `CType(z, TypeOfZ)`.

From your code, I assume that `z` is a bounding box of some sort? Anyway, you should declare it as what it is in the method, like

```
Function make(ByVal z As BoundingBox)
    ...
    If z.Bounds.IntersetcsWith(...) then
        ...
    End If
    ...
End Function
```